# Carousel thumbnail bootstrap 4 no carga correctamente todos los elementos

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

Me encuentro realizando una sección de artículo relacionados con bootstrap 4 pero, el problema es que nada más se alcanza a ver un item en vez de los 4 que debería tener el carousel.

```
<div class="container">

<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h3>ARTÍCULOS RELACIONADOS</h3>
</div>
<hr>    
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">

    <div class="carousel-inner row  mx-auto" role="listbox">            

        <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3 active">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://www.solerpalau.mx/multimedia/imagenes/productos/b0213267bdda4803590a1651776e24ea672736e1.jpg" alt="slide 3">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://www.solerpalau.mx/multimedia/imagenes/productos/3359c2cd6f609c23549adf36207725bc9ebf0418.jpg" alt="slide 4">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://www.solerpalau.mx/multimedia/imagenes/productos/d984e5d39ffbd8453676a837e5d0480fe48e5ede.jpg" alt="Card image cap" alt="slide 5">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400/000/fff?text=1" alt="slide 1">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=2" alt="slide 2">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
              <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://www.solerpalau.mx/multimedia/imagenes/productos/b0213267bdda4803590a1651776e24ea672736e1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
               <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">Extractores para Pared y Cristal</h6>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=6" alt="slide 6">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=7" alt="slide 7">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=8" alt="slide 7">
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg text-muted"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg text-muted"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

---

[image: Imagen donde solo se muestra un item]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cómo dice @Juan tienes en el código que has compartido dos 'divs' sin cerrar, pero el resto de tu estructurar parece correcta por lo que es posible que haya un problema en las llamadas a las librerías bien de 'CSS' bien de 'JavaScript' de 'Bootstrap', revisa que las esté cogiendo bien tu código. Te pongo tu código bien estructurado aquí:

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h3>ARTÍCULOS RELACIONADOS</h3>
  </div>
   <hr>    
   <div class="col-sm-12">
   <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
    <div class="carousel-inner row  mx-auto" role="listbox">            
    <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3 active">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://www.solerpalau.mx/multimedia/imagenes/productos/b0213267bdda4803590a1651776e24ea672736e1.jpg" alt="slide 3">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://www.solerpalau.mx/multimedia/imagenes/productos/3359c2cd6f609c23549adf36207725bc9ebf0418.jpg" alt="slide 4">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://www.solerpalau.mx/multimedia/imagenes/productos/d984e5d39ffbd8453676a837e5d0480fe48e5ede.jpg" alt="Card image cap" alt="slide 5">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400/000/fff?text=1" alt="slide 1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=2" alt="slide 2">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://www.solerpalau.mx/multimedia/imagenes/productos/b0213267bdda4803590a1651776e24ea672736e1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
           <div class="card-body">
                <h6 class="card-title">Extractores para Pared y Cristal</h6>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=6" alt="slide 6">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=7" alt="slide 7">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=8" alt="slide 7">
    </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg text-muted"></i>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
 </a>
 <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg text-muted"></i>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
 </a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo aca unos links de Carousel de Bootstrap 4

[Bootstrap 4 Carousel Oficial](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/)

Y link de  [StackOverflow en Ingles, de un tema similar.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41548605/7340464)

[codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/tBbcVXe1xZ) ofrecido por: [@ZimSystem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171456/zimsystem)

Donde sugieren utilizar `list-inline` en el listado de imagenes.

Ya que no has proporcionado el HTML completo, a veces puede ser una falla de tipeo en los linkeos de css / scripts o en el mismo html.

Otra "posible" solución que he encontrado es [utilizar este código](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-product-cart-slider)
y adaptarlo a tu codigo.

Comment: También por lo que veo en la imagen, creo que las imágenes utilizadas tienen un tamaño chico y se muestran en su tamaño original, dejando espacio en blanco.

Comment: No entendí muy bien este comentario. ¿El tamaño de las imagenes no es el adecuado?.

Comment: Es un poco confusa la imagen. La imagen que esta sola es lo que tienes?
 Y la imagen con los 4 es el resultado que quieres lograr? ... podrías colocar un snippet con el archivo html completo (proporcionando linkeos de css, js, etc) para poder visualizarlo en funcionamiento y poder corregir / ayudarte en solucionarlo?

Comment: @ManueelPerezz tambien he encontrado que faltan cerrar 2 divs (el container y uno de los col-sm-12)

Comment: @ManueelPerezz he agregado una "posible" solución.

Comment: Ya lo pude corregir. Muchas gracias Adjunot el snippet por si a alguien le interesa [aquí](https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/Q0Gpv)